# Azure domain verification: wildcard validation?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I'm creating several websites in azure and attempting to assign custom domain names to each. The website URLs will be of the form `app1.cloud.example.com`. Is there any way to bypass the validation for each domain name and just verify i own `cloud.example.com`?

The reason I want to do this is that eventually there may be hundreds of these websites, and so I would like to automate this, and it'll make my job a little easier if I can perform the validation once rather than having to code the creation of the validation CNAME record.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try *.cloud.example.com,   my situation is similar to you.  I put the wildcard domain on the websites.  At first, it wouldn't allow me to put the *.cloud.example.com on multiple websites.  but eventually , not sure when, i found out it allow me to do it now,  i am not sure this policy loosed on all azure accounts or just some accounts.

Comment: @liuhongbo Thanks for your comment, but I'm not sure how this helps. I'm not interested in adding a wildcard domain to my website in Azure, but being able to bypass the custom domain validation by validating the parent domain only.

Comment: If you just add the *.cloud.example.com on each of your web sites, you don't need to add the app1, app2  anymore.

Comment: @liuhongbo I still need to validate each app with a CNAME record though, which is my real issue. The actual setting of the host name on the web app isn't a problem, it's the validation which as far as I can see has to be a manual process.

Answer (score 0):

Try validating *.cloud.example.com.